# Unable to update to Openssh 8.4

Tags: 18.04, package-management, openssh

We received OpenSSH Information Disclosure Vulnerability CVE-2020-14145
CVE-2020-15778  on some ubuntu 18.04 Servers and the fix recommended is to upgrade to OpenSSH 8.4/8.4P1

But the current version of OpenSSH is 7.6 on all 18.04 servers and there is no OpenSSH 8.4/8.4P1 package available .

So please suggest if you will release packages for openssh 8.4 to update on 18.04 servers.

Please Note: we cant do the "build tools" method installation , our option is either we get package from ubuntu to update or please let us know if it is safe to ignore or disable this rule

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Security Team engineers usually **patch** vulnerabilities instead of upgrading to newer versions (there are a few exceptions). The main goal of an LTS release is to NOT upgrade most software, since that requires lots of new testing and breaks existing workflows. So openssh 8.4 on an 18.04 system is simply won't happen.

Patching a vulnerability, often using an upstream-provided patch, is a **100% acceptable way to mitigate the vulnerability**. It's the method Ubuntu (and Debian before it) have used for decades.

A "fix recommended" that involves changing major versions on an LTS release should be viewed very skeptically -- following such a recommendation is likely to break your system.

Folks who really want to use a newer version of OpenSSH for other reasons should use a newer release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response and the explanation . , so we should be good with openssh 7.6 with latest security patch for 18.04 for now .

Comment: Is the comment by sameer.yalvigi correct?  We are good with OpenSSH 7.6 if we have recently installed ubuntu 18.04? I visited the links shared by @user535733 but do not understand what I am seeing there.  Do I need to apply a June 2020 patch if I am upgrading to 18.04 in March 2021?  Thanks